# ASIFormDataRequest is not working i got nil values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

```
NSString *urlName=@"url name"; 
NSLog(@"url %@",urlName);
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlName];

ASIFormDataRequest *request1=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request1 setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request1 addPostValue:tokenName forKey:@"loginToken"];

[request1 setFile:savedImagePath forKey:@"file"];
[request1 setDelegate:self];  
[request1 startAsynchronous];
```

Here I am passing two parameters one is string and another one is image path.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to upload a file, but your method of doing so is incorrect.

An upload should be done like so :

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageName:fileName])
    [request setData:imageData withFileName:fileName andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"userfile"];
```